# FireStore PHP admin SDK for Firebase

Tags: php, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

**I want:**

I am new to firebase. I want to create custom authentication server using firebase hosting and fireStore database.

**I have done**

I have got php admin sdk for firebase "firestore" but i don't know how to use it to get data from firestore.

https://github.com/morrislaptop/firestore-php

I have download this and installed using "composer install"

after that i have created an index.php with the below contents

```
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use Morrislaptop\Firestore\Factory;
use Kreait\Firebase\ServiceAccount;

// This assumes that you have placed the Firebase credentials in the same directory
// as this PHP file.
$serviceAccount = ServiceAccount::fromJsonFile(__DIR__.'/serviceAccountKey.json');

$firestore = (new Factory)->withServiceAccount($serviceAccount)->createFirestore();

$collection = self::$firestore->getCollection('users');
$user = $collection->getDocument('123456');

$user->set(['name' => 'morrislaptop', 'role' => 'developer']);

$snap = $user->getSnapshot();
echo $snap['name']; // morrislaptop
```

**Error I Face**

I get the error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot access self:: when no class scope is active in C:\wamp64\www\site\php001\index.php on line 17

Comment: That error is because you are using `self` unnecessarily on the line: `$collection = self::$firestore->getCollection('users');`. `self` refers to the current class but your code is outside any class. See [Scope Resolution Operator on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php)